# Conditional If statement to set cells equal to 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is over 6000 rows and 300 columns. I need to know how to write code in vba that will allow me to read cells in a column and if says "no" then it sets the 3 cells to the right of it equal to zero. There is no error when I debug it, but the error is in the cell.Offset line. Thoughts?

Thank you in advance

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Object

 With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = .Range("C1:C6000")
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value = "no" Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
 End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the job. Using a For/Next loop, it reads each of the cells in Sheet 1 from A1 to the last cell in column A that has data. If the current cell has a value of "no", then it sets the value of the cell three columns to the right to the value 0.

```
    Sub SetTo0IfNo()
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim cell As Variant
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With Sheets("Sheet1")
            lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
            For Each cell In rng
                If cell.Value = "no" Then
                    cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
                End If
            Next
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End Sub
```

To set a range of cells to the right of the column A cells to 0, you would use slightly different syntax that still relies on the offset function. For example, to set the three cells immediately to right to 0, replace the above code line `cell.Offset(0,3).Value = 0` with the following code.

```
Range(cell.Offset(0, 1), cell.Offset(0, 3)).Value = 0
```

This approach is necessary because, unlike the worksheet `OFFSET` function which can return a reference to a range of cells, the VBA OFFSET can refer only to a single cell.

Comment: Thank you! It was so close. How would I make the three cells next to it 0 instead of just the third one?

Comment: See my amended answer, Sarah. Thx.

Comment: Chuff, the code works but Excel then shuts down and a pop-up says Excel Stopped Working. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't think of any way that the code itself would cause a shutdown. With such a big sheet, it's worth trying some speedup measures, in particular, turning off autorecalculation. This would delay recalculation of the formulas you have in the sheet until after the macro finished running. I'd also recommend getting out of any other applications you may have open. I've shown the changes to the code in my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still unable to keep the Excel Pop from appearing. The error is in the line of the offset. It does not say there is an error but that is where the program shuts down. This following code works correctly. I am using Excel 2010 in case there is a difference in syntax.    cell.Offset(0, 1).Select

Comment: @chuff "VBA OFFSET can refer only to a single cell". This is not correct, for example: `Range("A3:D3").Offset(0, 3).Value = "hi"`. That is, if we start with a Range larger than a single cell, Offset refers to a Range of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing chuff's code:

```
Sub SetTo0IfNo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
        For Each cell In rng
            If cell.Value = "no" Then
                'cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
                cell.Range("B1:D1").Value = 0
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The offset line has an error, is that the correct syntax for Excel 2010?

Comment: I'm not using Offset, that line is commented out with the apostrophe. You can delete it if you prefer.